# MissingMethodException when signing a Pdf with iText7 and Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, itext, bouncycastle

I'm trying to test iText documentation samples translated to Vb.Net, but on executing pdfSigner.SignDetached(...) I get next strange exception

> MissingMethodException:'System.Collections.IEnumerator
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Sequence.GetObjects()'

The code successfully reads both the pfx certificate and the source file, and creates the destination file but fails on the last step leaving the destination file corrupted:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.X509
Imports iText.Kernel.Geom
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf
Imports iText.Signatures
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs

Public Class SignHelloWorld
        Public Shared ReadOnly root As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) & "\tmp\itext7\"
        Public Shared ReadOnly DEST As String = root & "results\signatures\chapter01\"
        Public Shared ReadOnly KEYSTORE As String = root & "resources\encryption\myCert.pfx"
        Public Shared ReadOnly SRC As String = root & "resources\pdfs\hello.pdf"
        Public Shared ReadOnly PASSWORD As Char() = "1234".ToCharArray()
        Public Shared ReadOnly RESULT_FILES As String() = {"hello_signed1.pdf", "hello_signed2.pdf", "hello_signed3.pdf", "hello_signed4.pdf"}

        Public Sub Sign(ByVal src As String, ByVal dest As String, ByVal chain As X509Certificate(), ByVal pk As ICipherParameters, ByVal digestAlgorithm As String, ByVal subfilter As PdfSigner.CryptoStandard, ByVal reason As String, ByVal location As String)
            Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(src)
            Dim signer As PdfSigner = New PdfSigner(reader, New FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create), New StampingProperties())
            Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100)
            Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance()
            appearance.SetReason(reason).SetLocation(location).SetReuseAppearance(False).SetPageRect(rect).SetPageNumber(1)
            signer.SetFieldName("sig")
            Dim pks As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm)
            signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, subfilter)
            reader.Close()
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
            Dim directory As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(DEST)
            directory.Create()

            Dim pk12 As Pkcs12Store = New Pkcs12Store(New FileStream(KEYSTORE, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), PASSWORD)
            Dim [alias] As String = Nothing

            For Each a In pk12.Aliases
                [alias] = (CStr(a))
                If pk12.IsKeyEntry([alias]) Then Exit For
            Next

            Dim pk As ICipherParameters = pk12.GetKey([alias]).Key
            Dim ce As X509CertificateEntry() = pk12.GetCertificateChain([alias])
            Dim chain As X509Certificate() = New X509Certificate(ce.Length - 1) {}

            For k As Integer = 0 To ce.Length - 1
                chain(k) = ce(k).Certificate
            Next

            Dim app As SignHelloWorld = New SignHelloWorld()
            app.Sign(SRC, DEST & RESULT_FILES(0), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test 1", "Ghent")
            app.Sign(SRC, DEST & RESULT_FILES(1), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test 2", "Ghent")
            app.Sign(SRC, DEST & RESULT_FILES(2), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 3", "Ghent")
            app.Sign(SRC, DEST & RESULT_FILES(3), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.RIPEMD160, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 4", "Ghent")
        End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Usually get this when using different version of a DLL than the code was built with, the DLL the runtime found not having the referenced method. Have you used any binding redirects to  quell error messages about "the located assembly doesn't match the manifest" ?

Comment: My App.Config has a single 'bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.6.0" newVersion="1.8.6.0"' for BouncyCastle.Crypto which indeed is already version 1.8.6.0. I tried to remove it but I got same exception.

Comment: Ok and where is this code running when it gets this exception? Search that whole machine for the DLL name that contains bouncy castle crypto( you can check it in your references) - what versions of the dll do you find? Any old ones? Might one of those old ones e.g 1.7 be causing the problem because they don't contain the method, but the app is finding and trying to use the old dll anyway?

Comment: You are right, the code works successfully in another computer with outdated versions of BouncyCastle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see the current iText 7 development version (7.1.11-SNAPSHOT) is compiled against BouncyCastle 1.8.5, and indeed, in BC 1.8.5 you find in `Asn1Sequence.cs`

```
    [Obsolete("Use GetEnumerator() instead")]
    public IEnumerator GetObjects()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

but in BC 1.8.6 that method has been removed from `Asn1Sequence.cs`.

Thus, please currently still use BouncyCastle 1.8.5 when developing with iText 7 v7.1.10 or earlier.

---

As an aside, BouncyCastle is known for introducing API breaking changes in releases with only micro version changes. Most other projects would have removed methods (even if marked obsolete) only in a release with at least a change in the minor version if not in the major version.

When using BC, therefore, you always have to be very attentive which exact version to use.

Comment: can you please help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738068/itext-embedding-color-space-icc-profile-in-pdf-images

Comment: @ButaniVijay I don't really know much about the metadata specifics there. If you analyzed and showed the actual differences in the pdf files, I could probably help making the itext output similar to the acrobat output. But with only the output of that web site, I have no idea what needs to be changed.

Comment: thanks for your response. i just updated my questions and attached both the PDFs.

Comment: have you checked?

Comment: I'm currently busy with a project. Probably I'll find some time next week.

Comment: Wonder why they do major, minnor, patch versions if they do breaking changes on patches.